# The word 射 vs the word 短

Tags: traditional-characters

I have a thought that the following 2 words’ meaning is exchanged:
1) 射
2) 短

First of all, I am not saying I AM CORRECT or I want to make changes to these words, it is merely a discussion where I think this forum is about (‘to discuss the finer points of the Chinese Language’).  It's merely for fun and knowledge anyways and I want to know other's thought on it.

Here’s the argument:

(original):
射 -  shoot
短 -  short

(My thought):
射 - short. 身+寸 – body + inches, doesn’t that imply a body that’s only inches long, aka short?
短 - shoot. 矢+豆 – an arrow on a bean, kind of implying the action of shooting an arrow with accuracy?

I could be wrong by defining my arguement only destructing the word into parts and take their meaning, ignoring simplified Chinese / all other method of forming a word.  Any thought?

Comment: See http://wangjian930921.blog.hexun.com/84849426_d.html , http://www.tglin.idv.tw/essay/essay_lang12.htm

Comment: I really like your explanation to these two characters. If you are interested, the following two characters have exchanged meanings: 重 vs 出

Comment: @Madwyn hi Madwyn, thanks!  Could you clarify if 重 here (as pre-exchanged meaning) refers to "heavy", "layer", "important", or "repetition"?

Comment: 重 refers to "heavy", 出 refers to "depart" or "go out". I've learned this from an old TV program from CCTV. However, this is debatable. I think the best way to learn the truth is by looking at the ancient writings.

Comment: Interesting.  I will see if i've time for some googling later regarding to these 2 words.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

射 was originally written 䠶, that is a body and an arrow, giving the meaning shooting. But 身 is here a phonetic component, which just happens to also have a symbolic sense. 寸 is just how the original 矢 has been distorted in writing.

短 is actually an arrow 矢 shot into a 豆, which is not a bean but some sort of vessel. Why it means short is unknown, but we can note that another word for short, 矮, also contains 矢.

Comment: Thanks on the explanation on 射(䠶),  by distorted does it means it's been incorrectly written for too long, that 射 became the "correct" form?

Comment: “古代弓长箭短，所以用弓的长度作为长物的标准，以箭的长度作为短物的标准。” http://wangjian930921.blog.hexun.com/84849426_d.html

Comment: That's explains it NS.X.  Thanks for the link!

Comment: Now I can create a new one, 矢犬(shou3), 你这个  矢犬